# Не получается сделать запись в таблицу SQL

Tags: c#, sql, словари, insert

Есть словарь со значениями Dictionary<object, object> myPropertyResults и таблица с 50 столбцами.
Мне нужно занести значения из myPropertyResults в таблицу, но всегда выводит NULL.
Я же не могу все 60 значений вручную прописывать.

Я новичок и абсолютно не могу понять как мне это сделать.

```
private void ProcessorInfo()
        {
            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("server=LAPTOP-NDOBE5PK; Trusted_Connection=Yes; DataBase=Win32Project;");
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
            sqlConnection.Open();
            Dictionary<object, object> myPropertyResults = new Dictionary<object, object>();
            ManagementClass myManagementClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Processor");
            ManagementObjectCollection myManagementCollection = myManagementClass.GetInstances();
            PropertyDataCollection myProperties = myManagementClass.Properties;
            foreach (var obj in myManagementCollection)
            {
                foreach (var myProperty in myProperties)
                {
                    bool keyExists = myPropertyResults.ContainsKey(myProperty.Name);
                    if (keyExists == false)
                    {
                        myPropertyResults.Add(myProperty.Name,
                       obj.Properties[myProperty.Name].Value);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        myPropertyResults[Name] = obj.Properties[myProperty.Name].Value;
                    }

                }

                foreach (var myPropertyResult in myPropertyResults)
                {

                    InfoList.Items.Add(myPropertyResult.Key + ":" + myPropertyResult.Value);
                   
                        string cmdText = "INSERT INTO [ProccesorTab] VALUES (myPropertyResults)";

                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlConnection);

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("myProperty.Name", myPropertyResults);
                    
                }
            }
```

Comment: Если ключи в словаре совпадают с именами колонок, то просто используем их для составления строки sql-запроса. Если не совпадают, то перечисляем колонки вручную. Делов на пару минут.

Comment: Я бы вообще убрал промежуточный словарь и запрос в БД делал бы в цикле выше. Но это неважно.

Answer (score 0):

Оптимальнее всего будет сделать на сервере под это дело user-defined table type, данные залить в DataTable, и её использовать как значение параметра с типом этого созданного UDTT. Параметр либо передавать в хранимую процедуру, либо сразу в adhoc statement. Решение чуть хуже - сериализовать данные в XML, для вставки парсить его на сервере (опять же, внутри ХП или adhoc).